# doc2pdf - unable to connect or start own listener

Tags: php, linux, debian

## command

```
$file = '/var/www/test.docx';
move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file);
echo 'is file: '.is_file($file)."\n";

exec('/usr/bin/doc2pdf -o '.$file.'.new '.$file.' 2>&1', $out);
print_r($out);
```

## output

```
is file: 1
Array
(
    [0] => Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
)
```

This is a part of an upload script and is running as `www-data` under Apache..

The command line alone works fine from putty as `root`

The script has worked under `www-data`, but now it doesn't? :-/

## update I

```
apt-get install sudo
sudo visudo # added "www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/doc2pdf"
```

code:

```
exec('sudo /usr/bin/doc2pdf -o '.$file.'.new '.$file.' 2>&1', $out);
print_r($out);
```

error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host dyntest-amd-3700-2gb
```

## update II

```
echo "127.0.1.1 $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts
reboot
```

Comment: Add the `-v` option to your `doc2pdf` command and check the output of `$out`.  Also, `sudo` typically expects a tty.  Check your `/etc/sudoers` file for the `Defaults requiretty` option.  See this StackExchange post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122624.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either change the owner of /usr/bin/doc2pdf with the [chown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) command, or change the privileges of www-data user allowing to run commands as root without entering password. To do this, you'll have to edit **/etc/sudoers** file. Better not to edit it derectly, though. There's an util in linux used for this: [visudo](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.14/visudo.man.html).

**$sudo visudo**

add this to the very end of file

**www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/doc2pdf**

Save file and you're done. Don't forget to change this line of your php code as well (add sudo at the beginning):

```
exec('sudo /usr/bin/doc2pdf -o '.$file.'.new '.$file.' 2>&1', $out);
```

Comment: @EugeneSue - Is this secure way? I have seen many people saying to avoid doing this, is there any alternative in place of `**www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/doc2pdf**` ? Here is the reference on security issue - [Is it safe to allow www-data to execute privileged commands?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/is-it-safe-to-allow-www-data-to-execute-privileged-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Connect to ssh as root

**sudo visudo**

add

**www-data        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/doc2pdf**

and save :wq

Comment: when running `visudo` an error is returned.. have updated my question

Comment: It seems you're suggesting a file edit, right? So explain that. Maybe the OP doesn't have the same programs you're using in your example.